# Setting the default value to the current user in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a new table in Oracle 11g where the default value for a column is the currently logged in user. I need to do this is for logging purposes.

```
CREATE TABLE tracking (
  pk NUMBER(19,0) PRIMARY KEY, 
  description VARCHAR2(50),
  created_by VARCHAR2(128) DEFAULT CURRENT_USER
);
```

How can I write the `DEFAULT CURRENT_USER` section so it will take the current Oracle user as the default value? I know I could use a trigger, but I shouldn't have to...

Comment: how do you alter table add column for the current user so it records the user who modified the table last?

Answer (score 11):

You need to use [`USER`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions227.htm#SQLRF06156) not `CURRENT_USER`:

```
CREATE TABLE tracking (
  pk NUMBER(19,0) PRIMARY KEY, 
  description VARCHAR2(50),
  created_by VARCHAR2(128) DEFAULT USER
);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8a89e/2)

The maximum length of a user is 30, so you could reduce this and I would increase the size of your DESCRIPTION column unless you're very sure that everything will come in at less than 51 characters.

Comment: +1 @Ben - it's all true, and you beat me by about 2 seconds :)

Comment: To echo Gordon's comment a CREATED_AT column might also be a good idea.

Comment: Can `LOCALTIMESTAMP` be used as a `DEFAULT` value? Actually, one reason to use a trigger instead of a default would be to prevent anyone from setting the `created_by` or `created_at` columns explicitly.

Comment: [Yes it can](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ce61f/1) @EricJablow. I would normally just use a simple SYSDATE though... You're right about the trigger but if this is a proper tracking table then write access would not normally be granted to any user. You create a procedure in the schema the table resides in and grant execute on that procedure to everyone else (for instance). Or, it's only populated by system triggers etc.

Comment: @Ben, I'm only an amateur DBA.  Thanks.  I've had the requirement to add a creation date and user  to general tables before, though.

Comment: I'm not a DBA either @Eric :-). I would only add a USER where it's not obvious which user might have performed the action. For instance our DDL tracking tables have both the OSUser and the Oracle user. My process tracking tables only have a process ID. Absolutely _every_ table has a creation date though :-).

Comment: In my case, we were maintaining data tables, and we had the hard requirement to have the user who created the row, the time, the user who modified the row, and the modification time stored.  We were also using OLS.  We weren't writing tracking tables.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it solved my problem. I also had the 'created', 'last_updated' and a 'last_updated_by' fields, but I wanted a small example for this thread. But thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try `user` instead:

```
CREATE TABLE tracking (
  pk NUMBER(19,0) PRIMARY KEY, 
  description VARCHAR2(50),
  created_by VARCHAR2(128) DEFAULT USER
);
```

By the way, I also think `created_at` for the datetime is another useful default column.